# How to check if workflow is running.(WF4)

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I have 3 separate applications that use same persisted workflows. 2 of them are web apps and third is win form app that monitors WF. 
I am currently using my own queries to DB to check if WF is running or idle by processID guid.
Is there some native way to check if WF is running, idle ..... by by processID that I use for correlation that will not lock workflow instance.

Comment: And why isn't your approach the best one? I bet a native way would do something similar. Due to asynchronous nature of WF4 there isn't a 100% bullet proof solution. You've multiples ways to run a workflow and, because of that, you've multiple ways to check if it's running.

Comment: Anyway, consider [Tracking Participants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513993.aspx). It's used as a subscription mechanism. Subscribe to workflow events and wait for it to tell you its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to use logs, either your own logs in the database and a dashboard that indicates the status, or the built-in system monitor and performance counters from windows or windows server, those would be the standard methods in any IT environment.

Comment: I allso have that, but the problem with it it is not bullet prufe solution. I am seacrhing something in line with i.Load(procesID) but it must not lock instance.

Comment: But why would you want to check the process? a log tells you immediately the result of a faulty operation, even if it hangs, that means you are no longer receiving feedback, and performance counters are bounded to the operating system, they are reliable to monitor multiple processes at the same time, I wouldn't be so worried about such infrastructure.

Comment: I have 6 states ATM, they may or may not come more provisioning states because the continuing development and upgrades will continue for year or two. In begining was ok but now code for checking it state grows larger and larger. Because of that I need something native, something like when I  am pinging vOrchestrators WF, It returns me 3 statest, executig, completed and faulted.

Answer (score 0):

You can promote the correlation key, then you can query the instance base on the correlation key. [See here for an explanation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364726.aspx)

Comment: That is the problem, I want to avoid query, I am allready doing that. I need built in solution for that. I found something like that in WF 4.5